# How to end this function? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, codelite

I've been working on a quiz for my semestral work. It's a simple one since I'm a beginner. And I wanted to let the user insert the character of the option but it's not stopping after the character is inserted and I don't know how to solve it.

```
int giveAnswera (string answer)
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Enter the answer in form of a, b or c." << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (cin >> answer == "a")
    {
        cout << "✓" << endl; 
        cout << "Well done." << endl;
        x = x+2;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "×" << endl;
        cout << "You're wrong. You get no points." << endl;
        x = x+0; 
    }
 return x;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if (cin >> answer == "a")` simply be `if (answer == "a")`?

Comment: why inputting answer inside the function and passing also a value for the answer via parameter? you can choose one of the two otherwise it is bad idea. also `if (cin >> answer == "a")` doesn't check for the string value but instead it checks whether the input was correct or `correct` doesn't mean "a" but valid data type was assigned,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11, it doesn't compile.

In C++03, it *does* compile, but you try to read twice with `cin >> answer`, and the function is stuck waiting for the second input.
The condition should be just `answer == "a"`.

And since you're not using the value of the function's parameter for anything, you should remove it and use a local variable instead:

```
int giveAnswera ()
{
    string answer;
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Enter the answer in form of a, b or c." << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "a")
    {
        cout << "✓" << endl; 
        cout << "Well done." << endl;
        x = x+2;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "×" << endl;
        cout << "You're wrong. You get no points." << endl;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my saviour!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use

```
if(cin >> answer == "a")
```

instead use

```
cin >> answer;
if(answer == "a")
```